# Can I make prerequisites with same name from variable folders?

Tags: django, django-models, makefile

I want to write a makefile with prerequisites like this:

```
syncdb: apps/%/models.py
    manage.py syncdb %
    touch syncdb
```

(or resetdb, but let's just play with empty models.py and syncdb)

But this doesn't work, it updates syncdb every time. How can I make a rule that checks the timestapms of `models.py` files and runs syncdb commands with the folders where models.py are updated?

```
manage.py syncdb app-a app-b app-c ...
```

**Note:** I know that South is more appropriate for schema migrations, but here I just want to have a working rule in Makefile.

Comment: Not sure if there is a special reason not to use South, but I would highly advise looking into it.  `syncdb` doesn't handle schema migrations very well, but South is lovely for that.  http://south.aeracode.org/

Comment: I know that South is more appropriate, but to begin with I want to write a Makefile command. After that I can try South.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make's $? seems to be made for this job. Assuming that the MODELS variable contains all apps/*/models.py files (e.g. via the wildcard function), you can declare:

```
 syncdb : $(MODELS)
         manage.py syncdb $(dir $?)
```

and when apps/one/models.py and apps/two/models.py changed, the call will be

```
 manage.py syncdb apps/one apps/two
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare such a variable dynamically?

Comment: @culebrón: Yes. One example is "MODELS = $(wildcard apps/*/models.py)" in GNU make.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something with one touched file per app to comply with pattern rules.

```
apps/%/syncdb: apps/%/models.py
    manage.py syncdb $*
    touch $@
```

Then, the main rule will have dependencies on all the apps syncdb.

```
all_syncdb: apps/one/syncdb apps/two/syncdb ...
```

Or if you have a variable with all your apps:

```
APPS = one two ...
APPSSYNCDB = $(patsubst %,apps/%/syncdb,$(APPS))

all_syncdb: $(APPSSYNCDB)
```